# Return object at Index number from Array

Tags: iphone, arrays, search, nsarray

How do I determine the index number of `X` in an array sorted by `Y`?

I want to say something like *"The 6th record out of 26"* where *[array count]* is 26 and *'F'* is the record I'm looking for in an array containing the alphabet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
[array indexOfObject:@"F"];
```

This would return `6`

and:

```
[array objectAtIndex:6];
```

Which would return `F`

Answer (score 0):

Use the indexOfObject (or the like, according to your needs and object) message or the like on the array

Look at Apple's NSArray Class reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) and go the Instance methods section.